# incorrect password when computer is locked

Tags: windows, windows-xp, accounts

I have running a Windows XP SP3 Machine and I can't login after I have locked my Workstation. I changed my password and installed last Updates from Microsoft last Friday.

When Windows comes up, there is no problem to login. But after I locked it, it tells me that my password is wrong.

I pushed the client again into the domain, but doesn't help.

Thanks,
cyntaxx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your password have any symbols in, and do you have multiple languages installed? I found in the past that when I had US and UK English keyboard languages installed for some reason the locked screen would revert to US, and the symbols would be in different places on the keyboard.

Comment: My take on this usually goes somewhere along "make sure you're not watched, then try typing the password or parts of it in the user name box" to check all those things, keyboard layout, numlock, caps lock and so on...

Comment: Thanks for that hint. There is only one language installed, but in the registry there was a wrong entry: Keyboard Layouts 409. I changed it to 407 which is German and now it works.

Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 1):

If it is a laptop make sure that Numlock is off as some letters are used as numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are attached to a domain, your passwords may be out of sync if recently changed on a different machine.

Usually the procedure to kick it into gear is to lock and unlock your machine, or change your password from the C+A+D dialogue, so not to sure if it would remedy anything here.

Answer (score 1):

how many domain controllers do you have, are they replicating the password change you made?